# how to run 2 threads in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, event-dispatch-thread, thread-sleep

Hi i got following problem...
I have main jframe started like this:

```
public static void main (String args[]){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Form3 myF=new Form3();                    
        }
    });
};
```

in the jframe i have Jpanels. On jpanel i want to start 2nd thread.
I tried it like this:

```
try {
    while (DBAccess.haveResult("ASS"+harnessId)==null&&cancelCycle == 0) {

        thread1.sleep(3*1000);
        System.out.println("+++++++++");
        System.out.println(DBAccess.haveResult("ASS"+harnessId));
        res = DBAccess.haveResult("ASS"+harnessId);

    }

} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but I am unable to stop that thread and cant even cancel it, because main window stops reacting

to clarify my problem:
i have "Test" button on JPanel, which is starting test process. Test process consists of loop whiuch is repeating every 3 seconds, this loop checks database status. Problem is I am unable to stop this loop until the status appears in db (while condition), because window is busy after i click on "test". Even implementing runnable and putting test method into "run()" doesnt worked.

testbutton source code:

```
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Test")){
            run();}
```

run method:

```
@Override
    public final void run() {
        test();
    }
```

test method:

```
Map result_row =  DBAccess.addRow("ASS"+harnessId,htOperList.get(seqNumber-1).getNametestprogram(),"",null);
                if(result_row.containsKey("ADDROW")){System.out.println("Record inserted" );}
                Database db = null;
                Map res = null;                
                try {
                    while (DBAccess.haveResult("ASS"+harnessId)==null&&cancelCycle == 0) {

                        thread1.sleep(3*1000);                        
                        System.out.println(DBAccess.haveResult("ASS"+harnessId));
                        res = DBAccess.haveResult("ASS"+harnessId);
                    }

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: If the window stops reacting, it means that the loop doesn't run in a separate thread, but in the event dispatch thread, which causes the UI to freeze. Show us how you declare, initialize and start your thread.

Comment: added more source code

Comment: You don't start a thread by calling the `run()` method of a Runnable. This just calls the method in the current thread. Read [the concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: @Michael : Please have a look at [StartStopPause.java](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5021rcrhw3ewngd/StartStopPauseThread.java), that might can give you a faint idea as to how to do that, though as stated in the answer, `SwingWorker` is far better, since the programmer doesn't have to worry about GUI related updates, as they are automatically performed on the `EDT` :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are blocking the event dispatch thread. Use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for heavy tasks. Put the main DB operation in `doInBackround()`, and use `publish()` for the interim results.

If you need to stop it before `doInBackround()` completes, you can use `cancel()`. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/cancel.html) for notes about that.